# Unit Testing - Tests Cases vs. Multiple Methods

Tags: unit-testing, junit, nunit, xunit, vs-unit-testing-framework

When writing unit tests for the below example, would it be best practice to use TestCases (such as in NUnit), or to write multiple tests for verify the functionality?

Say that you want to test the RetrieveContact method below - it simply finds the corresponding Contact within an array and returns the result if found, otherwise will return null.

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private static Contact[] Contacts =
{
    new Contact() { Name = "Jim" },
    new Contact() { Name = "Bob" },
    new Contact() { Name = "Tom" }
};

public static Contact RetrieveContact(string name)
{
    return Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == name);
}
```

Would you test this with one method, using TestCases, like below?

```
[TestCase("Bob", "Bob")]
[TestCase(null, "ZZZ")]
public void Test_RetrievesFromContacts(string expectedName, string name)
{
    var ret = RetrieveContact(name);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedName, ret?.Name);
}
```

Or would you write two separate tests - one for valid contacts, or one for invalid contacts returning null?

```
[Test]
public void Test_RetrieveValidContact()
{
    var ret = RetrieveContact("Bob");
    Assert.AreEqual("Bob", ret.Name);
}

[Test]
public void Test_RetrieveInvalidContact()
{
    var ret = RetrieveContact("ZZZ");
    Assert.AreEqual(null, ret);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention in JUnit is that each **unit** test should test one  specific piece of functionality, one distinct path through the code-under-test. This convention strongly implies that you should not combine multiple, unrelated tests into a single test method.

So, in your example above you would write one test for each of the following:

- one for valid contacts
- one for invalid contacts

The rationale for this is:

- If you combine both of the above test paths into one test then a failure in the first path could prevent the second path from being run (thereby reducing test coverage)
- All other things being equal, a fine grained test case is likely to be more concise and legible i.e. less likely to be infected with conditionality such as `if firstPathFails then log and move on to second path` etc
- A test case which addresses the happy path ("valid contacts" in your case) will not have to be changed if your handling of "invalid contacts" changes. This is a reference to the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Notes:

- If several related methods within a test case require shared setup code then this can be implemented in a `@Before` method thereby reducing the size/reposibilities of each `@Test` method.
- The above convention does not imply that a single test method can only have one assertion.
- The above convention does not necessarily apply to coarse grained tests, such as integration tests, where an entire slice of an application may be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Although you tagged your post with junit, xunit and nunit, the code is obviously NUnit. The junit-oriented answer already posted is no doubt correct for junit, but I'll focus on the framework and language you are using.

The two examples you give are completely equivalent in NUnit. In the parameterized approach, each test case runs as a separate test independent of the other one. Each result is reported separately.

NUnit's `TestCaseAttribute` is no more than a syntactic shortcut to creating multiple tests, which only differ in the values used. Which approach you use is a matter of style and naming preference. The use of the `TestCase` approach seems to me to be more inviting to other programmers who may decide to add new data points.

You should also consider using `TestCaseSourceAttribute` if there are situations where the data type you want to use is not permitted as a constructor argument for an attribute in C#.

I have one reservation about your particular use case. It works fine when the "failure" case simply returns null with no other side effects. In most real-world scenarios, however, failure cases throw exceptions, produce error reports, etc. In general it's usually better to have an entirely separate method for the failure case or cases.